# PHP/Mpdf - Exibir todos os resultados do campo mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, mpdf

Estou tentando exibir todos os resultados de um campo no mysqli via php, e exibir no mPD, mas está retornando apenas 1 linha, alguém pode me ajudar por favor ?

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    include_once("config/conexao.php");
    $idPedido = $_GET['idPedido'];



    $result_usuario = "select pedidos.idCliente,pedidos.numPedido, pedidos.tipoPagamento, pedidos.total, itens_pedido.idPedido, itens_pedido.nome, itens_pedido.quantidade,itens_pedido.valorUni from pedidos, itens_pedido
        where pedidos.idCliente ='". $_SESSION ['clienteId']."' and pedidos.idPedido='$idPedido'";
        $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);  
        $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);


    $resulta_usuario = "select pedidos.idCliente,pedidos.numPedido, pedidos.tipoPagamento, pedidos.total, itens_pedido.idPedido, itens_pedido.nome, itens_pedido.quantidade,itens_pedido.valorUni from pedidos, itens_pedido
        where pedidos.idCliente ='". $_SESSION ['clienteId']."' and pedidos.idPedido='$idPedido'";

        $resultada_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);  
        $rowa_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    $pagina = 
            "<html>
                <body>
                    <h1>Comprovante do Pedido</h1>
                    Numero do Pedido: ".$row_usuario['numPedido']."<br>
                    Tipo de Pagamento: ".$row_usuario['tipoPagamento']."<br>
                    <br>
                    Lista de itens:   <br><br>
                    Nome: Preço Unitário:<br>
                    ".$rowa_usuario['nome']."".$rowa_usuario['quantidade']." R$".$rowa_usuario['valorUni']."

                </body>
            </html>
            ";

    $arquivo = "comprovante.pdf";

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' == '/tmp']);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($pagina);

    $mpdf->Output($arquivo, 'I');



    ?>
```

[image: resultado do script]

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema fazendo um JOIN, e depois fiz um foreach concactenando a variavel $html que é chamada na biblioteca mpdf para posteriormente ser exibida em PDF.

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT pedidos.*, itens_pedido.* from pedidos
                                INNER JOIN itens_pedido ON pedidos.idPedido = itens_pedido.idPedido
                                where pedidos.idCliente=$idCliente and itens_pedido.idPedido = '$idPedido'");
            $query->execute();
            $res = $query->get_result();
    $pagina = "<html>
                <body>
    <h3>Lista de itens:<h3>

                    <table width='400' border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nome</th>
                                    <th>Valor</th>
                                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                    ";
                    foreach ($res as $lista){
                    $pagina .= '<tr>'.
                    '<td align="center">'.$lista['nome'].'</td>' 
                    .'<td align="center">R$ '.$lista['valorUni']. '</td>' 
                    .'<td align="center">'.$lista['quantidade'].'</td>' 
                    ."<br>";
                    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]